# copy collection to another collection cloud firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, collections

I want to copy all users collection to subcollection "follow" please see attached screenshot
got the collection in data array

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
      const data = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        data.push({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() });
      });
      
      const filterUser = data.filter((da) => da.data.uid !== user.uid);
      setPostListData(filterUser);
    };
    getData();
  }, [db]);
```

[image]

Comment: You'll have to write code to query all the documents in the original collection, then write a copy to the new collection.  There is no shortcut for this.